# Where is SkipRequestValidation Attribute in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use SkipRequestValidation attribute on property of my model But that attribute is not exist in any assembly of default ASP.NET MVC 3 project.

Where is SkipRequestValidation attribute ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such attribute exists out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM. You have the [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute that you could apply on your model properties.

Comment: So why some of articles and sample mention about it ?

Comment: @Freshblood, I have no freaking idea. Probably some RC stuff. Maybe contact the authors of those articles for more info.

Comment: But still '<' and '>' tags are encoded even i used AllowHtml while binding model

Comment: @Freshblood, the `[AllowHtml]` attribute has nothing to do with encoding. It simply prevents from triggering an exception by the ASP.NET engine when you try to post characters such as `<` and `>`. If you have problems with encoding they are coming from the way you are posting your data or maybe from the way you are reading this data on the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow users to post html to your application, you must use `ValidateInput` attribute on methods that control the html contained requests; for example:

```
public class Home: Controller{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model){
        // do something
    }
}
```

here one or more properties of model, contains html value; Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this post was so helpful, and after replacing SkipRequestValidation  with [AllowHtml] issue is fixed and working fine.